# Is it possible to add a chatbot on a local page belonging to a global page structure?

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I'm working for an international client who relies on a global page structure. I would like to add a chatbot but only for the local french page, not all others ?
Possible ? Any tips ?

Comment: Child pages have their own unique IDs in Graph API, so I don’t see what exactly the problem is …?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each Page can have it's own bot. If you end up using a global page structure with multiple locales backed by the same app, the only thing to keep in mind if handling thread IDs from the Messenger Extensions SDK's getContext() function (if you use it)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/context#global